# Accessing array in php which is passed from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I pass a JSON array to a PHP function with ajax like this:

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'php/processing.php',
                data: {action: 'orderLater', kundenDatenArray: kundenDaten},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                }
            });
```

and now I want to generate a PDF out of this so I have to access the array in PHP.

I tried this:

```
function sendLater($in){

    $filename = "../pdfs/".$in[0]->vorname."_".$in["nachname"].".pdf";
    echo var_dump($in);
    //echo $filename;
    exit();
```

the $in var looks like this when I do var_dump

[image]

how do I access the array:

```
$in[0]->vorname

$in["nachname"]

$in[0]["nachname"]
```

non of these are working ...

Comment: Looking at the structure of your array $in["key"] should work. So $in["vorname"] and $in["nachname"] should return their values. Be aware though that the value for key "vorname" is an empty string so the PDF name would be "_u.pdf"

Comment: There is no `$in[0]` ... you have an associative array

Comment: yeah of course its empty at the moment I know ;) ... ... tried it bevor .. but now it works .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in["nachname"]` must return 'u', it is the right syntax.